# How to split lines only after date found

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have below content in a file.

```
Thu_Jun_04_09:30:22_2020=some_string:some_string=Thu_Jun_04_09:32:04_2020=some_str:some_string=some_string=Thu_Jun_04_09:35:05_2020=some_str:some_string,some_str
```

I want this line to split only when the date found. However date format will always be the same but date can be change. so I want the output in below format.

```
Thu_Jun_04_09:30:22_2020=some_string:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:32:04_2020=some_str:some_string=some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:35:05_2020=some_str:some_string,some_str
```

Please consider string can be added in between the line but it should be split only when the date found.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In the example input, you have `=` before the in-line timestamps which are not present in your desired output example (they would appear at the line ends there). Are they always present? Do you want them removed? Can we use them as part of the splitting indicator pattern?

Comment: @AdminBee Yes, you got it right, they will always present but I want them removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex pattern matches your date format:

```
((Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)_(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)_[0-9]+_[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+_[0-9]+)
```

With GNU `sed` you can add a `\n` before every date:

```
echo "Thu_Jun_04_09:30:22_2020=some_string:some_string=Thu_Jun_04_09:32:04_2020=some_str:some_string=some_string=Thu_Jun_04_09:35:05_2020=some_str:some_string,some_str"\
     | sed -Ee 's/((Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)_(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)_[0-9]+_[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+_[0-9]+)/\n\1/g'
```

If the resulting empty line at the beginning bothers you, you can pipe it though `sed -e '/^$/d'`

Comment: Thank you, This logic works.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would modify whatever it is that *produces* that data to insert newlines in the correct places.  If "some string" is truly *any* text, then it may be a date on the same format as the other dates on the line (`Thu_Jun_04_09:30:22_2020=Thu_Jun_04_09:30:22_2020=Thu_Jun_04_09:30:22_2020:Thu_Jun_04_09:30:22_2020`), which makes it difficult to work with.  It is therefore always helpful to include *actual* data in the question.

Using GNU `sed` specifically, with the data as given in the question:

```
$ sed 's/=\(..._\)/\n\1/g' file
Thu_Jun_04_09:30:22_2020=some_string:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:32:04_2020=some_str:some_string=some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:35:05_2020=some_str:some_string,some_str
```

This replaces the `=` before each `Thu_` with a newline.

The `Thu_` is matched with `..._`, i.e. "three characters and an underscore".  If that is too weak, you may want to use

```
sed -E 's/=((Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)_)/\n\1/g' file
```

instead, matching each valid weekday name explicitly.

Note that this requires GNU `sed` as standard `sed` can't insert newlines with the `s///` command (or use extended regular expressions with `-E` for that matter).